# How to run docker:dind to start with a shell

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want to run `docker:dind` and get a shell.
If I run `docker run --privileged docker:dind sh` it just exit.
The workaround is to run: `docker run -d --privileged docker:dind`
it starts in the background and then I can run `docker exec -it <container> sh` and get a shell.

But I want that it will start with a shell.
I created a Dockerfile:

```
FROM docker:dind
ENTRYPOINT sh
```

I built it:
`docker build -t dind2 -f Dockerfile .`

When I run `docker run --rm -it --privileged dind2` I get a shell but when I tried to run simple container `docker run busybox echo hi` it failed with:

```
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
```

Any idea how make `docker:dind` start with a shell without the workaround of running it in the background and then using `exec` to get a shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell docker to run **interactive** and with a **tty** to be able to use the shell.

```
docker run --interactive --tty docker:dind sh
```

or, for short

```
docker run -it docker:dind sh
```

Comment: while this works to get a shell - docker commands cannot be run in -it mode resulting with the same error (windows 11, docker on wsl2)

docker run -it docker:dind sh
docker pull nginx
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://docker:2375. Is the docker daemon running?

Answer (score 2):

Just like Andreas Wederbrand said. you can just

```
docker run -it docker:dind sh
```

and if you want to use Dockerfile. Just write like this.

```
FROM docker:dind
CMD ["sh"]
```

---

It shouldn't overwrite `ENTRYPOINT`. You can try to inspect `docker:dind` image.

```
docker inspect docker:dind
```

you can see entrypoint is a shell script file.

```
"Entrypoint": [
  "dockerd-entrypoint.sh"
   ],
```

of course, we can find this file in container. get inside the docker

```
docker run -it docker:dind sh
```

and then

```
cat /usr/local/bin/dockerd-entrypoint.sh
```

more about entrypoint you can see

https://medium.freecodecamp.org/docker-entrypoint-cmd-dockerfile-best-practices-abc591c30e21

Answer (score 0):

you need to run

> docker run -it docker:dind sh

then start dockerd service in background process:

> ./usr/local/bin/dockerd-entrypoint.sh&

Dont forget "&" at the end.